# How to create sympy equality with matrices

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I have two matrices I create like so:

```
A = sp.zeros(N**2, N**2)
f = sp.zeros(N**2, 1)
```

And I would like to see the equation A=f (with all the matrices' elements "spelled out"). Using:

```
display(Eq(A, f))
```

just results in an evaluation to `False`

How can I show the equality not without evaluating?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to set `evaluation=False` as arg in `Eq` *facepalm*